# Dojo ValidationTextBoxes blur focus... on focus

Tags: javascript, dojo

Using Dojo 1.7, my ValidationTextBox or NumberTextBox widgets don't hold focus.

```
<input name="mm" id="mm" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" data-dojo-props="placeholder:'Month', required:true" />
<input name="dd" id="dd" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberTextBox" data-dojo-props="size:2,placeholder:'Day',required:true" />
<input name="yy" id="yy" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" data-dojo-props="size:4,placeholder:'Year',required:true" />
```

If a value is deemed invalid, the tooltip shows, says the "invalid" message, but when I click on the textbox to change or add in the correct value, the textbox loses focus, and in this case it focus is sent back to the first textbox.  I've had this issue before and almost abandoned the validation part, but this seems like a silly issue.  All searches end in frustration, as does the entirety of Dojo's "documentation".

Does it in latest Chrome, FF and Safari builds which tells me it's not a browser issue.

Comment: You cannot use a DateTextBox?
Otherwise, is your first field valid? Let's say it is not, by default it has focus, you click on second, which causes the first to validate onBlur, then triggers invalid state, then get back focus to first textBox, which in turn triggers the validation on the second textbox, etc.
Focus can be tricky, how do you manage them? How do you validate your fields?

Comment: Suppose I could use a DateTextBox, but I've had this issue before with ValidationTextBox and figured I'd ask anyway. That sounds like the best explanation, yes.  As of now, the validation is handled by:

    btnSubmit.onClick = function(){
        if(form.validate()){
     form.submit()
        }
    }
You can see for yourself: http://calgamingleague.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I can found it.

[From your website](http://calgamingleague.com/) Your `</label>` is the principal.

Originally your `</label>` is stay next to `<input ....dojo.... />`

You have to move the `</label>`  stay before `<input ....dojo.... />`

like this

```
<label><span>City of Residence</span></label>
<input id="local" name="local" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" />

<label class="reqd"><span>Birthday</span></label>
<input name="mm" id="mm" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" data-dojo-props="placeholder:'Month', required:true" />
```

Thank you.

Comment: No no, thank you!  I guess I got a bit lazy on the markup to make styling it easier.